# Are outside and beyond interchageable here?

Tags: difference

A black car pulled up outside/beyond the barricades and Detective Blake stepped out.

Are 'outside' and 'beyond' interchangeable here?

Answer (score 1):

If barricades enclose an area, then there is an “inside” and an “outside.” The phrase “beyond the barricades” could refer to inside or outside and thus may be unclear. It is clearer to use “inside” or “outside” as the case may be.

If barricades do not form part of an enclosure, then “inside” and “outside” are not relevant terms. The term “beyond” may still be ambiguous if the point of view of the describer is relevant but not stated.

Answer (score 0):

I think "beyond" is equivalent only if the narrator is inside. If this is from  Detective Blake's point of view then "beyond the barricades" would (or might)  be inside, not outside.

Comment: (and Detective Blake would have a hard time stepping out of a car that pulls up on the other side of the barricade than he is)